# Unit test POST methods

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to unit test the below

```
@app.route('/questionSearch', methods=['POST'])
def search():
    body = request.get_json()
    search_result = Question.query.filter(Question.question.ilike('%'+body['searchTerm']+'%')).all()
    total_questions = Question.query.all()
    formated_result = [result.format() for result in search_result]
    return jsonify({
      'success':True,
      'questions': formated_result,
      'totalQuestions': len(total_questions)
      #'currentCategory': categories
    })
```

The way I am testing is:

```
   def test_add_question(self):
        res =self.client().post('/questions',
        json= {"question": "new Test question?", "answer":"Test answer", "difficulty":1, "category":1 })
        data=json.loads(res.data)

        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(data['success'],True)
```

It works but how do I avoid adding a million questions to the data base, currently every time I run the test script, it adds a new question to the test data base.

should I write a delete command in the teardown?

Comment: If you are writing a unit test, you should be mocking or avoiding the database altogether. For integration tests, you can commit to *a* database, though you might want to configure it so that your test method changes are rolled back immediately, leaving the database unchanged between tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rewrite your test using [mock.patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html) to mockup a database (and avoid touching the database at all) something like this:

```py
from unittest import mock

QUESTIONS = {"question": "new Test question?", "answer":"Test answer", "difficulty":1, "category":1 }

class TestRequestMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch("yourapp.db_models.Question", return_value = QUESTIONS)  # <- your package with Question data base model
    def test_add_question(self, mock_question):
        with app.test_client() as client:
            res = client.post('/questions', json=QUESTIONS)

            data=json.loads(res.data)
            self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
            self.assertEqual(data['success'],True)
```

Comment: Thank you, can you explain "yourapp.db_models.Question", I dont understand it.

Comment: @MightyPaladin It is a path to the object in your project tree structure you want to mock (in your case - _Question_ database model).